# Kafka not interacting with kaka-python code in docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

So I started a kafka and zookeeper instance on the host. Now I want to interact with it via two dockers - producer and consumer

The code in the PRODUCER docker is:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

i = 0
while 1:
  # "kafkaesque" is the name of our topic
  producer.send("stupid", str(i))
  i += 1
  time.sleep(1)
```

The code for CONSUMER docker is:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
consumer.subscribe(['stupid'])

for message in consumer:
    print (message.value)
```

The Dockerfile for CONSUMER is:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install kafka-python
ADD . /Consumer
WORKDIR /Consumer
CMD ["python", "consumer.py"]
```

The Dockerfile for PRODUCER is:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install kafka-python
ADD . /Producer
WORKDIR /Producer
CMD ["python","counter.py"]
```

Now i built both of them, and when I run it, like this:

```
docker run consumer 
docker run producer
```

Then for each of then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "consumer.py", line 3, in <module>
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 284, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 791, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

**

> But when I run each of them on the host machine, they work perfectly.

**

Can someone point out, how to solve this. I have some idea, as in the network port of the docker is not able to interact with the network port of the host, but i have tried EXPOSE and -p each of which is not helping me.

Answer (score 1):

check [Advertised hostname](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/README.md#advertised-hostname), run with:

```
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
(bootstrap_servers=[], api_version=(0, 9)))
```